# Set different color schemes for each buffer in Gvim

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I usually use gvim as an IDE, and I recently have started using the nerdtree plugin to see the project file structure. The issue is that my color scheme for syntax highlighting conflicts with the nerdtree (default) color scheme. This means that whenever I open nerdtree, all of the syntax colors are removed, and when I then reset the color scheme to syntax highlighting, the nerdtree colors disappear.

I have heard that this is possible in neovim, but for various reasons, I don't want to switch unless I absolutely have to. Is there any way to make different buffers have different color schemes in regular vim/gvim?

Comment: This is not currently possible in Vim.